# Specialization of template class for a given templated class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated class Matrix. I want to write a specialization for complex numbers. How can I do that ?

I suspect this won't work :

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix { ... }

template <typename T2>
class Matrix<std::complex<T2> > { ... }
```

But what will ?

Answer (score 3):

You need `;` after each class definition, but aside of that your syntax is correct and works.